# Get FPS from video using vlcj

Tags: java, vlcj

Is there a way to get the frames per second from vlcj without starting the video playing or displaying the video itself?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a programming site for programming questions. It isn't clear in any way that this is a programming question -- for a start it doesn't have any code. Please read [ask].

Comment: It is clear if you know vlcj, which is a java library. Hence the tags. I wouldn't expect anyone who doesn't know vlcj well to be able to answer. Welcome to SO yourself.

Comment: No, it isn't clear. Programming questions on SO require a lot more effort than this. I know exactly what vljc is. I'm here because this question has been flagged for quality review by the SO system.

Comment: I think you are being obtuse. It is a corner case API question, it doesn't need code examples etc. Caprica was quickly able to answer the question. It hadn't previously been asked on SO. The fact that some automated system flagged it is immaterial.

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid there is no way to do that.

This is not a limitation of vlcj, vlcj provides whatever LibVLC provides.

For applications where I need that sort of information, I resort to running something like the "MediaInfo" tool as a separate process (using commons-exec) and parsing the output.

https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

Comment: This question has a simple, factual answer. The OP asked is there a way, the answer is simply no. Quoting the linked page: What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”.

Comment: As it is, this question isn't a good fit for SO, and providing answers to such questions just encourages bad answers. If you read the [answer] link you'd have noticed near the bottom the section that starts with 'Answer well-asked questions'. This is where your answer is lacking.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I wondered if I had missed something in the API (such as parseMedia).

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a VLCJ component and a window (if having a GUI is acceptable for you)
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);

// Make sure the video is not visible nor audible
mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().audio().setMute(true);
mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().audio().setVolume(0);
mediaPlayerComponent.setVisible(false);

// Load the file. startXXX() functions are blocking calls, rather than playXXX(), until the video is ready.
frame.setVisible(true);
mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().startPaused("C:\\video.mp4");

// if there are several video tracks, make sure to take the index of the track with the same "id" value.
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().info().videoTracks().size(); ++i) {
  if (mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().info().videoTracks().get(i).id() == mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().video().track()) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}

// Get the frame rate (images per second)
double imgRate = (double)mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().info().videoTracks().get(index).frameRate() / mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().info().videoTracks().get(index).frameRateBase();
```